# in TCL how to operate the string?

Tags: string, tcl

I have a question about string in TCL:

```
HANDLE_NAME "/group1/team1/RON"

proc HANDLE_NAME {playerName} {
    #do something here
}
```

we pass the string "/group1/team1/RON" to the proc, but somewhere inside of the HANDLE_NAME, we only need the last part which is "RON", how to operate the input string and get the last part of the input(only RON) and set it to a variable?

can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
proc HANDLE_NAME {playerName} {
    set lastPart [lindex [split $playerName "/"] end]
    # ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And to add a fourth answer, if the string is actually a path to a file, use `file`:

```
set filename [file tail $playerName]
```

Answer (score 1):

Using string last to find the last forward slash. Then use string range to get the text after that.
http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/string.htm

```
set mystring "/group1/team1/RON"
set slash_pos [string last "/" $mystring]
set ron_start_pos [incr slash_pos]
set ron [string range $mystring $ron_start_pos end]
```

Answer (score 1):

To add a third answer, you can use `regexp` anchored at the end of the string too.

```
regexp {/([^/]+)$} $playerName -> lastPart
```

But the lindex/split solution by acheong87 is surely the more natural way if the strings you use are like file paths.